# react-native-webview avoid keyboard (iOS)

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

The [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) has in my experience proved difficult to behave as I want around the keyboard on iOS. It doesn't automatically change it's height when the keyboard is shown and its contents gets concealed by the keyboard.

It also behaves strangely wrapped with the [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview). In my case it seems to adjust the content of the WebView too much, approximately twice the height of the keyboard. This same behavior appeared when I manually listened for the keyboard open/close events and adjusted the height of the WebView accordingly:

```
  componentDidMount(){
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillShow", this.keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillHide", this.keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardWillShow", this.keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    Keyboard.removeListener("keyboardWillHide", this.keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
  }

  keyboardDidShow(event){
    this.setState({
      keyboardHeight: event.endCoordinates.height
    });
  }

  keyboardDidHide(event){
    this.setState({
      keyboardHeight: 0
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <WebView
        style={{flex: 1, maxHeight: Dimensions.get("window").height - this.state.keyboardHeight}}
      />
    );
  }
```

I've found a solution, not optimal, but a solution non the less. My answer is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

As I couldn't find any discussions on this particular behavior and no solutions that worked for me, I worked my way through the props of the react-native-webview docs. What finally worked for me in version 0.59.9 of React Native and version 5.11.0 of React Native WebView was as described above, manually setting the height of the WebView in the keyboard event listeners and setting the WebView prop `useWebKit={false}`.

Unfortunately this means that on the native side of the WebView, it's now using `UIWebView` which is deprecated and will in a future release be deleted.

Either way, this is what I'm rolling with and simply wanted to share my findings in case anyone finds themselves with the same issue.